# JavaScriptSerializer exceptions

Tags: vb.net

I am new to this topic, basically I have this JSON string:

```
"{"payChannleResult":{"lastestPayChannel":"","supportedPayChannelList":{"supportTopPayChannel":[{"name":"FastPay","cashierCode":"CREDITCARD","supportSecPayChannelList":{"supportSecPayChannel":[{"name":"BankA","cashierCode":"CREDITCARD_A"},{"name":"BankB","cashierCode":"CREDITCARD_B"},
{"name":"BankE","cashierCode":"CREDITCARD_E"},
{"name":"More","cashierCode":"CREDITCARD"}]}},
{"name":"Credits","cashierCode":"DEBITCARD","supportSecPayChannelList":{"supportSecPayChannel":[{"name":"BankF","cashierCode":"DEBITCARD_F"},
{"name":"BankI","cashierCode":"DEBITCARD_I"},
{"name":"More","cashierCode":"DEBITCARD"}]}}]}}}"
```

And I have classes for this:

```
<Serializable()> Public Class RootObject
    Private _payChannelResult As PayChannleResult
    Public Property payChannleResult() As PayChannleResult
        Get
            Return _payChannelResult
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As PayChannleResult)
            _payChannelResult = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<Serializable()> Public Class PayChannleResult
    Private _lastestPayChannel As String 'LastestPayChannel
    Private _supportedPayChannelList As SupportedPayChannelList

    Public Property lastestPayChannel() As String
        Get
            Return _lastestPayChannel
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _lastestPayChannel = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property supportedPayChannelList() As SupportedPayChannelList
        Get
            Return _supportedPayChannelList
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As SupportedPayChannelList)
            _supportedPayChannelList = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<Serializable()> Public Class SupportedPayChannelList
    Private _supportTopPayChannel As SupportTopPayChannel
    Public Property supportTopPayChannel() As SupportTopPayChannel
        Get
            Return _supportTopPayChannel
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As SupportTopPayChannel)
            _supportTopPayChannel = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class


<Serializable()> Public Class SupportTopPayChannel
    Private _name As String
    Private _cashierCode As String
    Private _supportSecPayChannelList As SupportSecPayChannelList

    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property cashierCode() As String
        Get
            Return _cashierCode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _cashierCode = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property supportSecPayChannelList() As SupportSecPayChannelList
        Get
            Return _supportSecPayChannelList
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As SupportSecPayChannelList)
            _supportSecPayChannelList = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<Serializable()> Public Class SupportSecPayChannelList

    Private _supportSecPayChannel As List(Of SupportSecPayChannel)
    Public Property supportSecPayChannel() As List(Of SupportSecPayChannel)
        Get
            Return _supportSecPayChannel
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of SupportSecPayChannel))
            _supportSecPayChannel = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

<Serializable()> Public Class SupportSecPayChannel
    Private _name As String
    Private _cashierCode As String

    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property cashierCode() As String
        Get
            Return _cashierCode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _cashierCode = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class



<Serializable()> Public Class LastestPayChannel
    Private _name As String
    Private _cashierCode As String
    Public Property name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property cashierCode() As String
        Get
            Return _cashierCode
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _cashierCode = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

And finally this is how I called the deserializer function:

```
Dim seriliazer As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer
Dim p As RootObject = seriliazer.Deserialize(Of RootObject)(strJson)
```

But it gives error: 
Type 'SupportTopPayChannel' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Please help me out, thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: I do used <Serializable()>, but somehow it is lost during CV.

Comment: Please post the a small reproducible example.

Comment: like?........................

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your VB class definitions aren't quite right.  The SupportedPayChannelList class has a property that is not declared as a list.  Use the below class definition (with List(Of added)).  Make sure to have Imports System.Collections.Generic if you don't already.

```
 Public Class SupportedPayChannelList
    Private _supportTopPayChannel As List(Of SupportTopPayChannel)
    Public Property supportTopPayChannel() As List(Of SupportTopPayChannel)
        Get
            Return _supportTopPayChannel
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of SupportTopPayChannel))
            _supportTopPayChannel = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```